# How to show divs dynamically after each button click based on number of items fetched from database?

Tags: javascript, database, html

I have some data in my database. I will fetch the data and will use the count. Now I have to display this data one by one in a div. So there will be first data and a next button. When I click on 'next' button,the second data fetched shows and so on until the end.
At the end the next button disappears and another button appears.

PLS Note: I am using python flask as back end

How to do this???

```
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-b-10 m-l-5" onclick="nextpart()" style="display:inline">Next ></button>
<div class="form-left-w3l" id="welcomeDiv1">
            <h6>Data : {{ id }}</h6>
        </div>
<div id="welcomeDiv2">
</div>
```

JS:

```
function nextpart() {
               document.getElementById('welcomeDiv1').style.display = "none";
               document.getElementById('welcomeDiv2').style.display = "block";
               }
```

Comment: A bit vague, don't you think? How are you fetching results? How do they reach your web page? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i am making use of flask to fetch data.. so will send data to template using flask as a list

Answer (score 0):

Save the data in an array. Create all the `div`s with a for-loop. Make them all `style="display:none"`.

Then `.show()` the first one and add a class like `active` to it.

Hook the Next-Button to a function: `.hide()` the `active` div and remove the `active` class form it. `.show()` the next sibling of that div and add the `active` class.

Use the same logic for the Prev-Button.

Comment: will this work if the number of elements fetched from db changes each time?

Comment: I cant say the number of incoming data...so cant specify the number of divs

Comment: can you get all data at once, or do you need to continually fetch more data whe clicken the next/prev buttons?

Comment: data will be fetched at  a stretch frm db and passed to template using python flask.. it will be like a list so will use for loop to extract each data in that list. so each extraction should come to each div

Comment: so on clicking each next some counter can be incremented and data from  that corresponding position in the list can be shown.. but how to make divs dynamic?